# css positioning elements for all resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with the differnt div elements used in the following code. It works perfectly on my resolution of 1024 x 768 . But the elements are not in the right place when the resolution changes.

[site](http://shivsample.comlu.com/)

I have uploaded this in a free webhosting service , so it might take time to load.

For Example, the watch customizer may not fit the screen.

The CSS File for the above is as follows.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote,         pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section{
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}    


body {
background: url(../assets/classy_fabric.png);

color: white;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: "Terminal Dosis", sans-serif;
text-shadow: 
    1px 1px 0 transparent,
    2px 2px 0 #101010;
overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
font-size: 75px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-shadow: 
    2px 2px 0 transparent,
    4px 4px 0 #101010;
}

a, a:visited {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 2px dotted;
transition: color 0.2s;
}

a:hover {
color: #AAA;
}

a:active {
color: lightblue;
}

.big {
display: block;
font-size: 45px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.3em;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-shadow: 
    2px 2px 0 transparent,
    4px 4px 0 #101010;
}

.wrapper div {
/*position: absolute;*/
position: relative;
}


.settings, nav {
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999999;
bottom: 10;
background: rgba(10,10,10, 0.5);
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 20px;
width:100%;

display: block; /* may help stop any text wrapping and display it inline. */
display: inline; /* same as above */
white-space: nowrap;/* ensure no wrapping */
overflow: hidden; 
}

.settings {
right: 0;
padding: 10px 20px;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.settings a {
border: none;
}

nav {
left: 0;
border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}

nav li {
float: left;
}

nav a {
display: block;
text-indent:50px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
border: none;
text-align: center;
transition: 0.25s;
}

nav li:last-child a {
border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}

nav a:hover {
background: rgba(15,15,15, 0.5);
}

.sp-canvas {
display: none;
}

.arrow {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
/*For home TAB*/
.demo { 
position: absolute;
top: -200px;
right: 0px;


}


/*For About us TAB*/
.description {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 440px;
}
/*For watch customizer TAB*/
.syntax {
position: absolute;
top: 180px;
left:130px;
width: 400px;
}
/*For retailers TAB*/
.scrollbar {
position: absolute;
top: -500px;
left: 1300px;
width: 0px;
}

.rotations {
left: 2185px;
top: 660px;
width: 460px;
transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(2.5em);
}

/*For FAQ TAB*/
.source {
position: absolute;
left: 2050px;
top: -3600px;
width: 400px;
transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(50px);
}

/*For contactTAB*/
.follow {
position: absolute;
left: 995px;
top: -4200px;

transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(50px);
}

.follow .big {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.highlight {
animation: highlight 0.2s alternate 6 ;
}

@keyframes point-down {
from {
    top: 0;
}
to {
    top: 5px;
}
}

@keyframes highlight {
to {
    background: lightblue;
}
}
```

I tried relative positioning, but it became even more complicated.

I would be grateful to you if you could help me.

Comment: so how your problem, solved?

Answer (score 0):

When targeting different browser sizes with CSS you should avoid using absolute positioning whenever possible. This is a good application for a CSS framework or some Javascript code. You may also find it useful to use CSS media queries to target specific resolutions.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. I tried relative positioning, but it messed up my watch customizer and it looked pathetic. I was not able to fix it.